# How to get submenu dropdown with images?

Tags: menus

I need to add submenus with images as in below snapshot.

Main menu has About,Deposits, Loans,...etc. and I need to add Kakulu Savings account, Apeksha Savings account ...etc under the Deposits Menu as sub dropdown menus with images.Can anyone explain how to do that? It's better if explain it with examples.

[image]

-cheers-

Comment: If you are just looking for plugin recommendation then this is not the correct place.

Comment: I changed. cheers

Comment: It is not enough to dump some code, your question needs to be about that code.... what is it actually that you are having trouble with? what is the wordpress API or concept you need to be clarified?

Comment: I updated my question. Could you please consider again and explain me in novice sound with examples?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not a WordPress related you know and there are other platform you can ask about this one,

anyway, if you didn't read this http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-a-dropdown-menu-with-html-css kind of article please read one.

I see you changed your post summary and thanks for that.

But before get answer something worth you have to try something because your solution can not be done with small code/example. It's need couple to step, if you want do it by your self.

1. Need to upload field in WordPress Menu Page
2. Working with Walker_Nav_Menu according to your styles and upload
   field.
3. use your custom menu function as walker hook.

But if you want to use use any mega menu plugin that will be easy and perfect for this.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/

http://wpmegamenu.com/

Comment: Max mega menu is worked. should try walker_nav_menu. cheers

Comment: You should accept @mohammad-limon answer ...